# MySQL Results From Seperate Tables And No Common Fields

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have two tables with completely different columns. For example:

```
A:                      B:
+-----+-------+------+  +------+------+-------+-------+
| id  | price | name |  | key | cost  | title | color |
+-----+-------+------+  +-----+-------+-------+-------+
| 123 | 10.00 | Boat |  | 456 | 12.00 | Ship  | red   |
+-----+-------+------+  +-----+-------+-------+-------+
| 124 | 8.00  | Car  |  | 457 | 5.00  | Truck | blue  |
+-----+-------+------+  +-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to return a single result set that maintains their separate data columns, but casts a common value to order the results by. For example, ordering by cost/price:

```
[1] key = 456  cost  = 12.00  title = Ship   color = red
[2] id  = 123  price = 10.00  name  = Boat
[3] id  = 124  price = 8.00   name  = Car
[4] key = 457  cost  = 5.00   title = Truck  color = blue
```

Since I don't want to JOIN, and there aren't any common columns for a UNION, is there anyway to do something like this?

EDIT:

I should note that the tables in my actual scenario contain many more columns. With a Union, it sounds like I would have to explicitly map those columns to each other, which isn't exactly ideal given the number of columns...

Comment: A `UNION` does not need common column names, just the same number of columns. You can use column aliases in one of the `UNION` halves to give them the same names, but even if you didn't, you could just order by the name  of the column from the top half of the `UNION`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski In my actual scenario, one table has far fewer columns than the other. How would I handle this discrepancy?

Comment: Looks like a `UNION ALL` operation to me. It's not clear what the resutset should actually look like,  Do you actuall need the row number enclosed in square brackets, the `key =`, `price = ` et al. literals? Each query just needs to return the same number of columns, with the same datatypes. If you have "missing" columns in one of the queries, you can just add placeholder literals in the SELECT.

Comment: @spencer7593 No, the result sets doesn't need to look exactly like the example, just contain the correct column => value pairs for each row returned by the query.

Answer (score 1):

To get a single resultset returned, we can use a `UNION ALL` set operation of two queries. The number of columns, and the datatypes of the columns need to match. We can use any expression, including literals.

```
SELECT v.*
  FROM ( SELECT 'key = '    AS col1
              , b.key       AS col2
              , 'cost = '   AS col3
              , b.cost      AS col4
              , 'title = '  AS col5
              , b.title     AS col6
              , 'color ='   AS col7
              , b.color     AS col8 
           FROM B b
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'id = '     AS col1
              , a.id        AS col2
              , 'price = '  AS col3
              , a.price     AS col4
              , 'name = '   AS col5
              , a.name      AS col6
              , ''          AS col7
              , ''          AS col8
           FROM A a
       ) v
   ORDER BY v.col4 DESC
```

Frequently with this type of `UNION ALL` result, we're interested in which query returned the row, so including an additional column as a discriminator is a common pattern.

I this example, we could use `col1`, since that will contain `'key ='` for rows from B, and `'id ='` for rows from A.

Note  that for the "missing" columns in A, we just used included a placeholder literal in the SELECT list to return a value for col7 and col8, so the number of columns and datatypes would match.

Answer (score 0):

All the fields are actually common `Key/ID` and `price/cost` are both numbers and `title/name` are both strings.

I would think the only solution here is to use the `UNION` operator and alias the column names to match one another and using a more generic alias name rather than `cost`/`price`, `title`/`name`.